# android back button doesn't close my dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I have an activity with a layout. I open a dialog with it. when I click back button, it doesn't work and don't close and then back to my activity.

I know I can solve it with overriding OnKeyDown() method, but I want to know why this problem occurred.

about two days ago, it worked perfectly and I haven't any problem with it.
now I want to know how to solve this problem?

Here is Dialog Class Code:

```
package digitalDreams.ddvolume;

import android.app.Dialog;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class DialogVolume extends Dialog {      

    Context cont;
    public DialogVolume(Context context) {
        super(context);
        cont=context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        .
        .
        .
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
//******   super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);  ***** if forget this line
           .
           .
           .
        return  super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);   
    }
```

it is simple app it control volumes of android.

and the activity, which call dialog is a simple layout.

Edit:

i Myself solve it!
i forget to call super class of OnKeyUp() function in overrided method
this is silly problem

thank you all

Comment: Hard to tell without some code.

Comment: code added to my post :)

Comment: didn't you any comment about this point that this code work perfect two days ago?!! :D

Answer (score 3):

> setCancelable(true)

Should work

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean)

> public void setCancelable (boolean flag)
>
> Added in API level 1 Sets whether this dialog is cancelable with the
>   BACK key.

Comment: how can i use it waza?

Comment: `dialog.setCancelable(true)`

Comment: doesnt work for me :( i add it at the first of my onCreate() method, but nothing happened!

Comment: Start with a simple dialog, then add your code piece by piece http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html The code of your activity is missing so cannot help more

Comment: I do this work in my code, and understand its from my onkeyup() function, i edit my Q, thank you waza :)